# Transposed matrix definition

Tags: matrices

Let $A \in K^{m \times n}$ with $A$ = $[a_{ij}]_{m \times n}$. The transposed matrix of $A$ is : $A^T = [(a^t)_{ij}]_{n \times m}$ with $(a^t)_{ij} = a_{ji}$ $\forall$ $i=1,2,...n$ and $j=1,2,...m$

Is this definition correct? My confusion comes with the $"i"$ and $"j"$

Comment: $a_{ij}$ is the entry of the matrix $A$ in the $i$th row and the $j$th column. For example $a_{23}$ is in the second row and the third column.

Comment: Yes, but my question was in the values ​​of "i" and "j", I think I misrepresented the class and put $i=1,2,...m$ and $j=1,2,...,n$.
That's why I started to meditate and arrive that this would be the correct definition but to make sure I ask.

Comment: Yes, $i$ should go up to $m$ and $j$ should go up to $n$, if $A \in K^{m \times n}$.

Comment: So the definition I put is wrong? What are the values ​​of $i$ and $j$ if the matrix is ​​of order $m \times n$?,thanks

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, this $i,j$ was indexing the rows and columns of $A^T$ not $A$, so yes $i$ will go up to $n$ and $j$ will go up to $m$. So your definition is fully correct.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the mistakes jeje :D

Comment: The trouble may arise also from you using the same $i,j$ in different meanings. First you write $A=[a_{ij}]_{m \times n}$, and here $i=1...m$ (rows), $j=1...n$ (columns), but then you write $A^T = [(a^t)_{ij}]_{n \times m}$ where $i=1...n$, $j=1...m$ are rows resp. columns of the **transposed** matrix.

Comment: Yeah, I'am confused for that

Answer (score 0):

range of $i$ and $j$ will not change. It means for all $i=1,...,m$ and $j=1,...,n$ is true